# Pandas: how to unstack by group of columns while keeping columns paired

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I need to unstack a contact list (id, relatives, phone numbers...) so that the columns keep a specific order.

Given an index, dataframe UNSTACK operates by unstacking single columns one by one, even when applied to couple of columns

Data have

```py
df_have=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID': {0: '100',   1: '100',  2: '100',  3: '100',  4: '100',  5: '200',  6: '200',  7: '200',  8: '200',  9: '200'},
 'ID_RELATIVE': {0: '100',  1: '100',  2: '150',  3: '150',  4: '190',  5: '200',  6: '200',  7: '250',  8: '290',  9: '290'},
 'RELATIVE_ROLE': {0: 'self',  1: 'self',  2: 'father',  3: 'father',  4: 'mother',  5: 'self',  6: 'self',  7: 'father',  8: 'mother',  9: 'mother'},
 'PHONE': {0: '111111',  1: '222222',  2: '333333',  3: '444444',  4: '555555',   5: '123456',  6: '456789',  7: '987654',  8: '778899',  9: '909090'}})
```

Data want

```py
df_want=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID': {0: '100', 1: '200'},
 'ID_RELATIVE_1': {0: '100', 1: '200'},
 'RELATIVE_ROLE_1': {0: 'self', 1: 'self'},
 'PHONE_1_1': {0: '111111', 1: '123456'},
 'PHONE_1_2': {0: '222222', 1: '456789'},
 'ID_RELATIVE_2': {0: '150', 1: '250'},
 'RELATIVE_ROLE_2': {0: 'father', 1: 'father'},
 'PHONE_2_1': {0: '333333', 1: '987654'},
 'PHONE_2_2': {0: '444444', 1: 'nan'},
 'ID_RELATIVE_3': {0: '190', 1: '290'},
 'RELATIVE_ROLE_3': {0: 'mother', 1: 'mother'},
 'PHONE_3_1': {0: '555555', 1: '778899'},
 'PHONE_3_2': {0: 'nan', 1: '909090'}})
```

So, in the end, I need ID to be the index, and to unstack the other columns that will hence become attributes of ID.

The usual unstack process provides a "correct" ouput but in the wrong shape.

```py
df2=have.groupby(['ID'])['ID_RELATIVE','RELATIVE_ROLE','PHONE'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
```

This would require the re-ordering of columns and some removal of duplicates (by columns, not by row), together with a FOR loop. I'd like to avoid using this approach, since I'm looking for a more "elegant" way of achieving the desired result by means of grouping/stacking/unstacking/pivoting and so on.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Solution have main 2 steps - first grouping by all column without `PHONE` for pairs, convert columns names to ordered catagoricals for correct sorting and then grouping by `ID`:

```
c = ['ID','ID_RELATIVE','RELATIVE_ROLE']
df = df_have.set_index(c+ [df_have.groupby(c).cumcount().add(1)])['PHONE']
df = df.unstack().add_prefix('PHONE_').reset_index()

df = df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)])

df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns, categories=df.columns.tolist(), ordered=True)

df = df.unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

---

```
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]    
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    ID ID_RELATIVE_1 RELATIVE_ROLE_1 PHONE_1_1 PHONE_2_1 ID_RELATIVE_2  \
0  100           100            self    111111    222222           150   
1  200           200            self    123456    456789           250   

  RELATIVE_ROLE_2 PHONE_1_2 PHONE_2_2 ID_RELATIVE_3 RELATIVE_ROLE_3 PHONE_1_3  \
0          father    333333    444444           190          mother    555555   
1          father    987654       NaN           290          mother    778899   

  PHONE_2_3  
0       NaN  
1    909090
```

If need change order of digits in `PHONE` columns:

```
df.columns = [f'{a.split("_")[0]}_{b}_{a.split("_")[1]}' 
                 if 'PHONE' in a 
                 else f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]    
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    ID ID_RELATIVE_1 RELATIVE_ROLE_1 PHONE_1_1 PHONE_1_2 ID_RELATIVE_2  \
0  100           100            self    111111    222222           150   
1  200           200            self    123456    456789           250   

  RELATIVE_ROLE_2 PHONE_2_1 PHONE_2_2 ID_RELATIVE_3 RELATIVE_ROLE_3 PHONE_3_1  \
0          father    333333    444444           190          mother    555555   
1          father    987654       NaN           290          mother    778899   

  PHONE_3_2  
0       NaN  
1    909090
```